# How to concatenate two integer variables and make a float variable?

Tags: c, math, arduino, operators

I have two integer variables and the result has to get stored in a float. I wanted to concatenate two integer variables and store them as a floating value. Let me know a method of joing two integer values.

Example.
I HAVE BELOW FUNCTION CALL. WHERE I AM STORING THE VALUE RECEIVED FROM KEY TO VARIABLE lat_int AND lat_float. i WANTED TO COMBINE BOTH AND STORE IN LATITUDE , WHICH IS GLOBALLY DECLARED AS FLOAT VALUE.

```
void setCustomCoordinate(int cord_para[])
{
 lat_int=cord_para[0];
 lat_float=cord_para[1];
 long_int=cord_para[2];
 long_float=cord_para[3];

  latitude=(lat_int+lat_float)/100);
 longitude=(long_int+long_float)/100));


}
```

Comment: Why do you need the intermediate float?

Answer (score 6):

this is not really a code question, but more a basic arithmetics question:

> how do I transform two values so `a` and `b` give `a.b`?

simply by using addition and multiplication:

```
int a=10;
int b=20;
float r=0;

r = a+(b/100f);
```

thre's no need for an operator to do that (it takes two CPU instructions to calculate this value, calling a function would be more expensive) ; and it's not called "concatenation", but addition and multiplication (again).

If you want a concatenation, you should instead have "10" and "20" be strings that you concatenate using a dot, as an example, this is a string concatenation:

```
printf("%s.%s", "10", "20");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

> math.h

```
int nDigits = floor(log10(abs(the_integer))) + 1;
```

then you can get a power of 10:

```
int power = pow(10,nDigits);
```

and finally:

```
float result = a + b / power;
```

Answer (score 1):

No extra library file (such as math.h) is needed, the `concat` function can be created like this ...

```
float concat(int a, int b){
    float c;
    c = (float)b;
    while( c > 1.0f ) c *= 0.1f; //moving the decimal point (.) to left most
    c = (float)a + c;
    return c; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this integer values to float.

For example consider **10 as 10.00** and  **20 as 00.20**

Then perform addition operation a+b which will give you outpout as 10.20

Answer (score 0):

You can just divide b by 10^p where p is its string length then add a to b
example
if a is 1000 and b is 323 so b length = 3
so you will divide b by 1000 it will be 0.323 and then just add a to b

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to concatenate two integers, you could use c++ stringstream's to accomplish that, something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a = 4;
  int b = 5;
  ostringstream oss;
  oss << a << "." << b;
  istringstream iss(oss.str());
  float c;
  iss >> c;
  cout << c << endl;

  return 0;
}


Output: 4.5
```

[Ideone example](http://ideone.com/0qniTy)

Comment: cause that wouldn't create a float variable. He could now use the float variable `c` which would be `4.5` for whatever he wants to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the combination of `printf()` and `strtof()`:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    float f;
    char *buf;

    if (asprintf(&buf, "%d.%d", a, b) > 0) {
        f = strtof(buf, NULL);
        printf("%f\n", f);
        free(buf);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```